# When to mark notification as read? When one visits the page or clicks on the notification?

Tags: php, mysql, database, performance, notifications

I am making a website that will have a notification system that is like Facebook.

Each notification would redirect the user to a page, and on that page, I would mark any unread notification as 'read' as follows:

```
UPDATE notification SET status AS 'READ' WHERE ...
```

It is working well but the problem is every time when a user go to a page, even if there is no unread notification for the user, the query would still run. Though it does not make any difference to the end users, I wonder if it will create any performance issues.

I am thinking if I should update the database based on the click event on the notification dropdown. I want to listen to others about it first before implementing it. I want to know what's the normal practice when dealing with the notification system. Thanks!

Comment: I think this should belong in the [ux stack exchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: This is not about user experience, but more about performance and system design

Comment: Okay. After rereading it, I realise what you mean.

Comment: If you're really looking at performance though, shouldn't you be using a boolean instead of `varchar` when you mark it as read?